# For Loop will only display jButton Icons Once

Tags: java, swing, icons

I'm trying to make it so that Every time I open up this JFrame all the players swords Icon's appear on the buttons. It will do it the first time I click it but if i exit out then click it again no Icons appear. Have been wanting to smash my keyboard the pass hour any help would be awesome. Thank you.

```
public static ArrayList <JButton> buttons = new ArrayList();

public SelectWeapon() {
    initComponents();

    buttons.add(jButton1);
    buttons.add(jButton3);
    buttons.add(jButton4);

    for(int i = 0; i < Player.swords.size(); i ++){

        buttons.get(i).setIcon(Player.swords.get(i).getIcon());
    }

}
```

This is the the button  I click to display the JFrame above.

```
 SelectWeapon menu = new SelectWeapon();
    menu.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to empty out the `buttons` array before you repopulate it in `SelectWeapon()`.

Comment: Thank you so Much. That worked! Why is that?

Comment: When you add the new buttons, they go into the list past the indexes that you are using in the loop to set the icons. (That is, after the first time, `buttons.get(i)` retrieves an old button that you hadn't cleared out, not one of the new buttons you just added.)